# Windows 8 HTML5 - Adjusting the layout of a Split App?

Tags: javascript, css, windows, html

How is it that I can adjust the location of the buttons (group?) on the main page to my liking, or otherwise reformat them? Is it in the CSS files, or somewhere in the JS files? I do not believe a code example is required for this question.
Any suggestions appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default template for split app doesn't contain any button groups they are mere divs,In case you need to alter their styles you need to make changes in items.css page.I believe you want to style the left pane..

Try the following CSS in items.css page,

```
  .itemspage .itemslist .item {
    -ms-grid-columns: 1fr;
    -ms-grid-rows: 1fr 90px;
    display: -ms-grid;
    height: 100px;//You can make adjustments to the height here
    width: 250px;
}

    .itemspage .itemslist .item .item-image {
        -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
    }
```

Comment: I've been looking through here, changing values this way and that, but all it ever seems to do is majorly screw it up.

Comment: what is the exact change you want?

Comment: Well, any way I can simply adjust the position of the buttons on the main page. Possibly smaller and along the left border in one column.

Comment: Thank you, it works; but it is distorted and more editing will be required to make it nice. Thanks for your help:)